# Why does systemd notify fail my service if I run script with sudo

Tags: sudo, systemd

I am creating a systemd service that needs to run a bash script with sudo privs. I noticed that when I run it, it hangs forever in "status=Activating".

To try to replicate it, I setup a toy example. I have a systemd unit that will run a very simple long-running bash script that does a systemd_notify right away and then loops forever. I run the script with sudo. However, the service fails to start and I get this error:

```
Aug 20 14:21:48 ip-10-110-103-202 systemd[1]: Starting "Testing"...
Aug 20 14:21:49 ip-10-110-103-202 sudo[24772]: No status data could be sent: $NOTIFY_SOCKET was not set
Aug 20 14:21:49 ip-10-110-103-202 systemd[1]: test.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
```

test.service:

```
[Unit]
Description="Testing"
Requires=network-online.target
After=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=notify
User=consul
Group=consul
ExecStart=/usr/bin/sudo /home/psengupta/long_test.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

long_test.sh:

```
!/usr/bin/env bash
set -euo pipefail

systemd-notify --ready --status="Started"
while true
do
        echo "Press CTRL+C to stop the script execution"
        # Enter your desired command in this block.
done
```

When I remove the sudo in front of the command, it works fine!
e.g
ExecStart=/home/psengupta/long_test.sh

Why does using the sudo before running the long_test.sh script actually fail my service? I am not very familiar with this stuff and not sure why $NOTIFY_SOCKET is not set with the sudo command usage. Ideally, I would like to set it and run the script with sudo and notify when it is started.

Answer (score 0):

Read `man sudo sudoers` and use `sudo -E` to pass your whole set of environment variables along.